# Fubini theorum for integrating 1 dimension of a 3d convolution

Tags: integration, convolution

I have 3D volume that is convoluted with a 3D blur function. Both are positive and integrate to a finite value. I can see experimentally (meaning playing with matlab) that this is true:

$\int_{-a}^{a }(g\star f)(x,y,z)dz=(\int_{-a}^{a}g(x,y,z)dz)\star (\int_{-b}^{b }f(x,y,z)dz)$

I see that wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Integration , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Corollary)  has the following property of convolution:

$\int_{R}^{ }(g\star f)(x)dx=(\int_{R}^{ }g(x)dx) (\int_{R}^{ }f(x)dx)$

How could this be proven for my case?  Sorry I am just a programmer if this is obvious.

**edit:** doing a little more math, but still not there.

so I expand out the convolution to give the following integral

$$h(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb{Z}}^{ }\int_{\mathbb{X}'}^{ }\int_{\mathbb{Y}'}^{ }\int_{\mathbb{Z}'}^{ } g(x',y',z')f(x-x',y-y',z-z')dx'dy'dz'dz$$

I then rearrange the integrals to put the integrals over z in the center (is this correct?)

$$h(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb{X}}^{ }\int_{\mathbb{Y}'}^{ }\int_{\mathbb{Z}}^{ }\int_{\mathbb{Z}'}^{ } g(x',y',z')f(x-x',y-y',z-z')dz'dzdx'dy'$$

I then ignore the x and y integrals for a moment, to get

$$\int_{\mathbb{Z}}^{ }\int_{\mathbb{Z}'}^{ } g(x',y',z')f(x-x',y-y',z-z')dz'dz$$

which matches the equation from the wikipedia page.  Both functions are always positive, so I can change this to

$$\int_{\mathbb{Z}}^{ }\int_{\mathbb{Z}'}^{ } \left | g(x',y',z') \right |\left |f(x-x',y-y',z-z') \right |dz'dz$$

since g does not have any z in it

$$\int_{\mathbb{Z}}^{ } \left | g(x',y',z') \right |\left [ \int_{\mathbb{Z}'}^{ }\left |f(x-x',y-y',z-z') \right |dz\right ]dz'$$

which gives:
$$\int_{\mathbb{Z}}^{ } \left | g(x',y',z') \right | \left \| f \right \|_{1} dz' = \left \| g \right \|_{1}\left \| f \right \|_{1}$$

(I have no idea what $\left \|  \right \|_{1}$ means or how this step works, hard to find a symbol on google!)
So putting back the integrals of x' and y', this gives

$$H(x,y)=\int_{\mathbb{X}'}^{ } \int_{\mathbb{Y}'}^{ }\left \| g \right \|_{1} \left \| f \right \|_{1} dx'dy' =???$$
which is where I lost it

Comment: Wrap your math markup with dollar signs to get it to show correctly.

Comment: I just figured that out.  Thank you.

Comment: I guess, the last term of the integration also goes from $-a$ to $a$ instead of $b$. Is the integration  one dimensional, or is it  over a volume (cube), perhaps a whole line/space? If not, do we have restrictions for the supports of $f,g$?

Comment: x,y, and z are cartesian coordinates.  Both f and g are always positive (optical density) g is an 3D density, while f is a blur, either a 3D gaussian or something like a cone that falls to zero as 1/z^2. the second integral is integrated over b because the convolution works over g(x,y,z) and f(a-x,b-y,c-z) where a,b,c are the coordinates of the resultant spot, so when they are seperated, they must have a different range to make sense.  Does this answer your question?  The formula seems to match the corollary from wiki.

Comment: Yes, but to obtain exact equality, we need to integrate it over all $\Bbb R$, I suppose.

Comment: That is fine to integrate over all $\Bbb R$. Both functions fall to zero fairly quickly. I was trying to mimic the form in the wiki page as closely as possible.